# How to make xml format tabular data in android

Tags: java, android, xml

I am new in java and android tried lots of time for this but don;t any idea, don;t me give me downvote or comment, waiting any answers from yours. I have data structure in tabular format like this:

**First question is, I am confuse how to put xml format in picture data and get appropriate value below my question.**

[image]

If i am **Young** and **Goa**, how to display current data of boys and girls. `Boys: 4409 and girls:950`

I have tow input field. **Age Group** and **City**.

**if:**

```
Age Group-> Child
Cirty->Delhi
```

then **output**:

```
boys:66 and girls:90
```

and so on others.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new Java class like this

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MyData {

    private static HashMap<String, String> items = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public static void addItem(String Group, String City, String boys, String girls){
        items.put(Group.trim()+"," +City.trim(),boys.trim() +"," + girls.trim());
    }

    public static String[] getItem(String Group, String City){
        return items.get(Group.trim()+"," +City.trim()).split(",");
    }

    public static void clearData(){
        items.clear();
    }
}
```

Now When you need to put the data, then add it like this

```
MyData.addItem("Young", "Goa", "Boys:4409 ", "girls:95");
MyData.addItem("Child", "Delhi", "Boys:66 ", "girls:90");
```

And when you need to retrieve it then get it like this

```
String[] arr = MyData.getItem("Young", "Goa");
String boys = arr[0];
String girls = arr[1];
```

Hope this solves your problem

Comment: My main concern is, How to make xml file of above tabular data., I want to get data that xml from from web. any idea sir?